# Im trying to copy the rotation of a gear to an object but the gear is inbetween 2 axis so cant copy the constrain gear to an exact axis

Tags: constraints, axis

Hi so I'm trying to copy the rotation of a gear I made to an object but the rotation of the object rotates on the Z axis and I want the gear to rotate on on the X and Y axis at once as the gears make up a circle, I'm able to constraint the gears to diffrent axis (object rotatates on the Z axis while the gear rotates on the X or Y but not both) is there any way to make the gear constraint the rotate to an object and still rotate on two axis?

Comment: A sketch or picture with annotations would help a lot to understand what u are doing and trying to achieve

Comment: All figured out, I had to change the axis it changed on to local so it rotated on the new axis (the axis X+Y) so it rotates on the axis of the object not the world axis. I can still send a video if you would still like to see it?

Comment: If you solved it, congrats! Would be great if you could write an answer to it so other people with same problem can learn from u